# Machine learning - Evolving intelligence

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Having some understanding on the concepts and steps of building a ML model covering these aspects -

1. Understanding and categorising the problem as - Supervised or
   Unsupervised, Regression or Classification or Clustering, etc.
2. Feature designing i.e. features/input parameters to consider
3. Splitting the data into train and test sets. (Cross-Validation is
   another important concept in here.)
4. Comparing various models (like KNN, SVM, Random Forest, etc.) and understand which fares well. Basically, cross validate the scores and understand the prediction capabilities.

Doubt::

How the newer data is being fed to ML to keep it updated and better prediction?

Comment: Sorry , but I'm still not getting the SO protocol which is violated in my post. Should i ask this in Data Science exchange, or the title, or some code snippet?

Comment: It is better if you ask it in [cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.

Comment: @mods: I have asked this question in a better format and with lot more details on 'Data Science' stack exchange, and receiving very informative suggestions from community. Can I please delete this entire thread since this is no longer useful, and also to regain my posting power? I don't think editing this post is any longer required.

Comment: I got the answer to my question, and that's the problem of `model staleness` - https://medium.com/thelaunchpad/how-to-protect-your-machine-learning-product-from-time-adversaries-and-itself-ff07727d6712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. nothing has to be finalized, once you get new data, you can retrain your model with all relevant data, or update your model(another iteration of gradient descent for linear regression for example).
2. if it is a relevant data., i.e. data from the same distribution, it shouldn't "hurt" the model.
3. this is essentially the same question as #1. the details depends on the model. some models you just have to retrain with all relevant data. some model you can just update with new data.